# eslint How to allow constantcondition?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

In my pakcage.json , the generated config is

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
     "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
```

but then when I write in my vue.confgig.js :

```
 const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: ('mode' === 'test') ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
    plugins: [
```

i get an error :

```
rror: Unexpected constant condition (no-constant-condition) at vue.config.js:5:15:
```

how should I write the rule in my package.json file ?

Comment: George is right, but if there's a reason you're comparing two constant, you can disable eslint for this line by placing this comment on the line before: `// eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition`

Comment: Ok thanks do it had to be done case by case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive this error because you are comparing 2 strings

```
'mode' === 'test'
```

this will never be true

you should instead propably be doing

```
process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
```